# Select com Linq definir os primeiros caracteres no where

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

Como posso definir no `Linq` o mesmo que defino na clausular `Where do sql server` da forma abaixo ..

```
select * from tb_CentrosCusto cc
where cc.Clasificacao like '1.4.1%'
```

Ou seja só buscar o que começa com o que estou passando, estou usando o `Contains`, mas assim ele verificar se o que estou comparando contem na `string` independente se é no começo ou no fim.

```
List<Int32> Ids = new List<Int32>();
foreach (var ClasificacaoPai in CCPais)
{
    var IdCentroCusto = CentrosCusto
         .Where(CC => CC.Clasificacao.Contains(ClasificacaoPai))
         .Select(CC => CC.IdCentroCusto)
         .ToList();

    if (IdCentroCusto.Count > 0)
        Ids.AddRange(IdCentroCusto);
}
```

Veja como vem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só quero que venha o que começa com **1.4.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abaixo algumas formas de "Like".

```
string.Contains("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern%'
string.StartsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE 'pattern%'
string.EndsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern'
```

Segue um exemplo.

```
List<BaseClaim> BaseClaims = new List<BaseClaim>()
    {
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "11123411" }, //match 1
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "11123123" }, //match 2
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "44423411" }, //match 3
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444AAAA" }, //match 3
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444BBBB" }, //match 3
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444QWQEQW" }, //match 3
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "2314" },
        new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "3214" }
    };
    List<UserProfile> UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>()
    { 
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="%112341%", ID="1459" }, //match 1
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="%123", ID="1459" }, //match 2
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="444%", ID="1459" }, //match 3
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="5555", ID="1459" },
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="2222", ID="1459" },
        new UserProfile(){ WPId="1111", ID="4444" },
    };

    char[] asterisk = { '%' };
    List<BaseClaim> result = BaseClaims.Where(b => UserProfiles.Where(u => u.ID == "1459").Any(u => u.WPId.StartsWith("%") && u.WPId.EndsWith("%") ? b.WPId.Contains(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) :
                                                                                                    u.WPId.StartsWith("%") ? b.WPId.EndsWith(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) : 
                                                                                                    u.WPId.EndsWith("%") ? b.WPId.StartsWith(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) :
                                                                                                     false)).ToList();
    //this will result to getting the first 3 BaseClaims
```

Comment: Boa... havia passado errado. Valew

Answer (score 1):

A forma encontrada para fazer isso foi com o método  `StartsWith` da classe `String`

Ficou assim

```
.Where(CC => CC.Clasificacao.StartsWith(ClasificacaoPai))
```

[Fonte aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx)